Azure Logic App workflow automation keyvault secret reference error
I have created and standard app and a workflow using rest apis, and when I went back to logic app designer and see at the get azure keyvault secret step it is showing the connection is invalid and unable to retrive. The API connection is already created and assigned proper pivileges. But when I am creating using restapis, it is not working for the first, and if I reconfigure then it is working. But I don't want to do like that I want to know why it is not working for the first time.
I don't want those manual steps in my automation using rest APIs.

Can you provide the rest apis you are using with basic details and how are deplying or using them
